# Android - How to post with authorization header

Tags: android, model-view-controller

I post with authorization header,the code like

```
public static String doPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    /* 建立HTTPPost对象 */
    HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(url);
    httpRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    httpRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    String strResult = "doPostError";
    try {
        /* 添加请求参数到请求对象 */
        httpRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

        HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
        /* 发送请求并等待响应 */
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
        /* 若状态码为200 ok */
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

            InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();//获取内容
            final String result = streamToStr(is);
            /* 读返回数据 */
            strResult = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        } else {
            strResult = "Error Response: "
                    + httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        strResult = e.getMessage().toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        strResult = e.getMessage().toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        strResult = e.getMessage().toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.v("Cloud Service", strResult);
    return strResult;
}
```

the server side is a web api.I post the request

```
final String api = "api/RealTime/GetDtu";
                List<NameValuePair> list=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneId", station.getPhoneId()));
```

But the server does not received any json parameters.Web api has only one parameter is PhoneId.Why I call web api but the parameter is null??

Answer (score 0):

The entity you set in the request is transferred to the server as the POST parameters.  The only parameter you're setting is the phoneId.  So why would you get any more?  If you want more you need to set them.

Comment: yep,I set post parameters like doPost(host + api, list);

Comment: Not in the code you gave us you didn't.  You set only one parameter, which you said you got.  That looks like its working as expected to me.

Comment: I debug my server side web api "api/RealTime/GetDtu",the web api authoritied,but the parameter is null